# Multiplication table using 2D arrays and methods

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm a new student having a bit of trouble with this assignment, but the powerpoint notes and other online guides don't seem to help. If anyone can give me a pointer it would be much appreciated!

```
private static int[,] GenerateTT(int size)

       {       
            int[,] table = new int[size,size];      
            for (int i = 1; i < size+1; i++)      
        {      
                for (int j = 1; j < i+1; j++)      
                {      
                    table[i-1, j-1] = i * j;      
                }      
            }      
            return table;      
        }      
        private static void DisplayTT(int[,] table)      
        {      
            Console.WriteLine();       
            Console.WriteLine("Here is the times table for that size:");      
            Console.WriteLine();      
            for (int i = 1; i <= table.Length; i++)      
            {      
                for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++)      
                {      
                        Console.Write("{0}\t", table[i-1, j-1]);     
                }      
                Console.WriteLine("\n");      
            }      
                Console.WriteLine();      
        }
```

The output is supposed to be like this (if you enter 4 for example):

1 2 3 4
2 4 6 8
3 6 9 12
4 8 12 16

But what I'm getting is this, plus it crashes at DisplayTT(table):

1
2 4
3 6 9
4 8 12 16

here's the relevant part of the Main method if it helps.

```
int size = GetValue("Please enter the size (4-20) of the times table: ", 4, 20);        
Console.WriteLine();        
int[,] table = GenerateTT(size);        
DisplayTT(table);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change the inner loop hi-bound:

```
private static int[,] GenerateTT(int size)
{       
    int[,] table = new int[size,size];      
    for (int i = 1; i < size+1; i++)      
    {      
        for (int j = 1; j < i+1; j++)    // <-- change  i+1  to  size+1
        {      
            table[i-1, j-1] = i * j;      
        }      
    }      
    return table;      
}
```

---

I'd rather keep the loops start from zero:

```
private static int[,] GenerateTT(int size)
{       
    int[,] table = new int[size,size];      
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)      
    {      
        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)      
        {      
            table[i, j] = (i+1) * (j+1);      
        }      
    }      
    return table;      
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `GetLength(X)` Property for multi dimensional arrays where `X` is index of dimension.

```
for (int i = 0; i < table.GetLength(0); i++)      
{      
    for (int j = 0; j < table.GetLength(1); j++)      
    {      
            Console.Write("{0}\t", table[i, j]);     
    }      
    Console.WriteLine("\n");      
}
```